# Least upper bound property and greatest lower bound property

Tags: real-analysis

(a)

$$S = (-∞, 1) \cup [2, 3) \cup (3, 10]$$

(b)

$$S = (-∞, 1) \cup [2, 3) \cup [9, 10]$$

---

Can someone explain to me, simply, why the first question, $S$ wouldn't have LUP?  And why the second one does?

Comment: Well, no. They both have a least upper bound, 10.

Comment: I thought so too.  But, in a, I was told that 10 was an upper bound, and so is 9,8,7..., but it's not the LEAST upper bound.

Comment: Wait, what? 9, 8, 7 are certainly not upper bounds of $S$. Since $10 \in S$, an upper bound cannot be smaller than 10.

Comment: Yes, upper bound can not be smaller than 10 if 10 was the least upper bound though, which I was told was not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one, $[2,3)$ has no least upper bound *in* $S$, whereas in the second one, the least upper bound of $[2,3)$ *in* $S$ is $9$.

Comment: Thank you! Just noticed that now.